# Show image before ajax send and hide when its done

Tags: jquery, ajax

I load my post with infinite scrolling, and when i send ajax i show loading image, when its done - image must hide, but it not work in the end of pages we load.
Part of ajax function code:

```
beforeSend: function( xhr){
                $('body').addClass('loading');
                if(!$('.loader').length > 0) {
                $('.latest').append('<div class="loader"><i class="icon">!</i></div>');

                $('.loader').addClass('loading').show();
                }

            },
            success:function(data){
                if( data ) { 
                    $('body').removeClass('loading');
                    $('.latest .items').delay(200).append(data);

                    $('.loader').hide();

                    current_page++;
                }
            }
```

What is wrong with code, why image dosent hide when last ajax method was send ?

### Solution:

thanks for help, u use `complete:function() { }` for hide my image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code .hope will works for you.  you should include complete: tags to hide you data.

$.ajax({url: 'action.php',
                    data: {},
                    type: 'post',

```
                beforeSend: function() {
                    // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                   // This will show ajax spinner
                },
                complete: function() {
                    // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
                    // This will hide ajax spinner
                },
                success: function (result) { 
                    if(result=="success") {
                        $.mobile.changePage("#Flexilast20");                         
                    } else {
                        alert(result); 
                    }
                },
                error: function (request,error) {
                    // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
                    alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                }
            });
```